# Z3/OCaml free constants

Tags: z3

Out of curiosity, I wonder how I can add a free constant to a Z3 solver via the OCaml API, i.e., something corresponding to

```
(declare-const k!0 (_ BitVec 5))
```

The following attempt yields an `invalid argument` exception.

```
let cfg = [("model", "true"); ("proof", "false")] in
let ctx = mk_context cfg in
let solver = Solver.mk_solver ctx None in
  Solver.add solver [Expr.mk_const ctx (Symbol.mk_int ctx 0) (BitVector.mk_sort ctx 5)]
```

Is there a way to do this without adding a constraint which contains the constant and simplifies to true?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Solver.add` expects a term of Boolean sort, i.e., an assertion, but in this example a constant of bit-vector type is added, that's why it complains about an invalid argument.

In general, constants (or any other functions) do not need to be declared explicitly in a separate step via the API, they can be constructed and used in expressions/assertions without declaring them.

By default, such constants will be assumed to be existential, otherwise they'll have to be quantified explicitly (see the Quantifier module).